# SESSION maxlifetime issue

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-variables

I am using session to store user values.

This code is on top of `login.php`:

```
// If user is logged inn, redirect to index.php
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

This code runs when a user successfully logged in from `login.php`:

```
// Password is correct, so start a new session
                            
session_start();
                            
session_regenerate_id();
                            
$_SESSION["loggedin"] = TRUE;
$_SESSION["name"] = $name;
```

This code is in the top of all .php pages in my website, for example `index.php`:

```
<?php
// Start session to use session in page.
session_start();
// Redirect if user is not logged in
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```

I have a page named `testphpini.php` to check the `phpinfo()`. This is how the session variables looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the Local Value for session.gc_maxlifetime has been changed to 28800(8 hours), but still users are having issue being logged out after a short amount of time.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: Anyone, please?

Comment: Master value is much shorter and you're using a shared directory: any other PHP process will remove your session data.